Flyback converter secondary side soft start
I’m designing a flyback converter that outputs ±150 V, ±60m A, and while the overall circuit functions well in simulations, I’m having trouble with the soft-start function.
It doesn't get activated for the first 1 ms (or until the output voltage reaches 70 V). When it activates, it only works until TL431 cathode voltage reaches 20 V. I used a zener to clamp to cathode voltage at 20 volts. Soft-start function works better without the zener but TL431 cathode reaches 120 V so I need to use it.
I think the problem is that when the voltage is clamped the optocoupler diode is no longer forward biased and there's no current in the transistor side, so the compensation pin voltage is pulled high. I used LM5156EVM-FLY, PMP10666 and SNVC240 as reference. I used the Excel document to calculate the feedback loop component values.
Thanks in advance for any advice!
Circuit parameters:

Input: 30 V
Output: ±150 V ±60 mA
Frequency: 300 kHz
Transformer turns NP:NS1:NS2  1:4:4
Peak Current Limit 2.2 A

Edit: As @Jens suggested, adding a pnp transistor between SS and COMP pins works well for soft-start adjustment. It works even without the soft-start network on the secondary side.
With 330 nF SS capacitor:

Schematic:

Feedback Loop:

TL431 Cathode:

TL431 Reference Pin:

LM5156 Compensation Pin:

Output Voltage:


What is the aim of the soft start?

@TimWilliams I want to prevent high start-up currents

But high operating currents are acceptable? i.e. if the output is overloaded or shorted, the resulting current flow is acceptable?

No but there's already a current limit function in the PMIC. The problem is LM5156 datasheet says if the current limiting occurs for a long period the IC will go into hiccup mode and stop switching. I don't want it to activate hiccup mode accidentally during startup.

Why not use the SS pin on the controller?

@Andy It doesn't work for SSR Isolated Flyback topology.

Figure 10-10 in the datasheet suggests an optional primary side soft start for your configuration. Did you try this?

Increase SS capacitor.

@winny As I understand the datasheet, the SS pin will not work in a configuration, where FB is grounded.

I think Figure 10-10 is valid for primary side regulation. SNVC240 LM5155 Excel Quickstart Calculator says if the feedback is isolated a secondary side soft-start circuit must be used. I increased the capacitors it didn't change anything.

In figure 10-10 the PNP controls the start ramp until the secondary side regulator can take over. To me this sounds like a solution if you use a big capacitor.

Show with an oscillogram that there is no difference before and after changing SS capacitor value.

Datasheet: "Hiccup mode overload protection is available in the LM51561 device option". Are you not in fact using the LM5156 (no -1) then?

@TimWilliams I missed that. Thank you for pointing this out. I still think it's a good feature to have. This is my first real task in my job and I'm kind of nervous. I don't want anything to go wrong.

@Jens Thanks a lot. I addes the transistor on the primary side and it works well. I don't know why the documents says it wouldn't work. I even removed the soft-start network on the opto-coupler side and it still works. The circuit is simpler too.

As @Jens suggested, adding a pnp transistor between SS and COMP pins works well for soft-start adjustment. It works even without the soft-start network on the secondary side.
